# How to post using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I testing using curl for post. i created 3 php files "app, source, result". first php is app to post. second is source. third to process post value. How to post from app to source.php and get result,php. I get nothing.

first php

```
$data = [ 'user' => 'myself' ];
$headers = [
"User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.0.10992/35.5561; U; hr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10",
 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
];

$options = [
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
];

$ch = curl_init("localhost/source.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $res;
```

> Source php

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user">
</form>
```

> Result php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user'])){ echo $_POST['user']; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending data via a POST or PUT request, two common formats (specified via the Content-Type header) are:

application/json
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Many APIs will accept both formats, so if you're using curl at the command line, it can be a bit easier to use the form urlencoded format instead of json because

the json format requires a bunch of extra quoting
curl will send form urlencoded by default, so for json the Content-Type header must be explicitly set
This gist provides examples for using both formats, including how to use sample data files in either format with your curl requests.

curl usage
For sending data with POST and PUT requests, these are common curl options:

request type

-X POST
-X PUT
content type header

-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

-H "Content-Type: application/json"

data

form urlencoded: -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" or -d @data.txt
json: -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' or -d @data.json
Examples
POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded
application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the default:

curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
explicit:

curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
with a data file

curl -d "@data.txt" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
POST application/json
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
with a data file

curl -d "@data.json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data

Answer (score -2):

send parameter with post method on cmd.exe:

> Sample Command :

curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://sample.com/index.php